# Would I get Swap Files if I upgrade from 16.10?

Tags: swap, 17.04

I don't have a swap partition because I have two partitions for my files +
 windows partition so i can't make any more partitions on the disk.
would I get swapfile when i upgrade from ubuntu 16.10 to 17.04? or do I have to freshly install it?

Comment: I think the default now in Ubuntu 17.04 is `swap file` rather than `swap partition` so I think you will. But remember its still in dev so might behave funny...

Comment: @George It is released now.

Comment: @fkraiem so we can upgrade?

Comment: @George Of course you can.

Comment: I hear Ubuntu Unity is to be dropped for gnome, am I right?

Comment: @george that'll happen in 18.04

Answer (score 0):

During an upgrade, the system won't change how you currently handle virtual memory. No swapfile will be set up. No swap partition will be created.

If you want to add swap, it's not difficult. Either `gparted` to make a new partition (you can have as many partitions as you want if you use logical partitions) or follow any of the [tutorials on adding swapfiles](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04) that are available.